# wordpress running locally on docker

Tags: wordpress, docker

I'm trying to run Wordpress locally (docker) but when I try to install a plugin or a theme a get a TLS issue.

[image]

Any idea what can be the issue? Is it possible to play with Wordpress locally over HTTP?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are you downloading the plugin from? it seems to be signed by a self certificate rather than a trusted CA.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm using my company computer... it's certainly a local firewall that proxy my communicaitons.

If anyone has some information about how it works please comment on that post. I mean does a host firewall can act as proxy? I'm outside of my company network. I don't understand how this decryption/encryption is possible.

Comment: I have a local proxy configured by my company